# Is there any way to incorporate the radar cross section(RCS) of a target in scipy.signal.chirp?

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing

I currently am using the scipy.signal.chirp to generate a transmitted chirp in which time delay is added and then it is multiplied with a received signal to get the beat signal which is further used for signal processing. The amount of received signal depends on the radar cross section of the detected target. The source code of the function is written in c language and I am not able to find the code.

This is the code that I am currently using:-

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import scipy.signal
    import scipy
    no_samples = 500000
    chirp_duration = 2e-3
    f0 = 76e9
    f1 = 78e9
    c = 3e8
    target_range = 100
    target_velocity = 40
    bandwidth = 2e9
    slope = bandwidth/chirp_duration

    time_delay = 2*target_range/c
    sampling_rate = no_samples/chirp_duration
    change_in_frequency = slope * time_delay

    time_interval = time_delay
    frequency_at_time = f0 + (slope * time_interval)

    t_axis = np.linspace(0, chirp_duration, no_samples)
    trans_chirp = scipy.signal.chirp(t_axis + time_delay , f0=frequency_at_time , f1=f1 ,       t1=chirp_duration, method='linear')
    received_chirp = scipy.signal.chirp(t_axis, f0=f0, f1=f1, t1 = chirp_duration, method = 'linear' )
mix = np.multiply(received_chirp,trans_chirp)
```

Comment: I have trouble understanding your question.

Comment: Does radar cross section vary over time? You could scale the signal by a constant corresponding to the cross section by writing `received_chirp * rcs_constant`. Otherwise, I'm not sure what you mean. Can you explain the process of incorporating RCS?

Comment: @Nick ODell No the RCS does not change over time it is basically is the area of the reflective portions of the drone from where the radiations reflect back to the receiver.